# Visual Studio GIT with Symlinks / Linked Files in Solution

Tags: git, visual-studio, svn, version-control, filesystems

I have a file structure as below:

```
D:\SharedCodeDir\codefile1.txt
D:\SharedCodeDir\codefile2.txt
D:\SharedCodeDir\...
D:\Solution\Project\projectfile1.txt
D:\Solution\Project\projectfile2.txt
D:\Solution\Project\...
```

I need to include `D:\SharedCodeDir\codefile1.txt` and other "shared" files in my VS project. I have several options to accomplish this:

1. I can create a symlink to `D:\SharedCodeDir\codefile1.txt` in `D:\Solution\Project\` so that `D:\Solution\Project\codefile1.txt` will really be a symbolic link to real file at `D:\SharedCodeDir\codefile1.txt`
2. I can simply add `D:\SharedCodeDir\codefile1.txt` to my VS project as a link in the Add File dialog.
3. I can create a hard link, so that both `D:\SharedCodeDir\codefile1.txt` and `D:\Solution\Project\codefile1.txt` will point to the same data on disk. This is least desired.
4. I could create a folder symlink / junction in `D:\Solution\Project` to `D:\SharedCodeDir`, so that `D:\Solution\Project\SharedCodeDir` is really a symlink / junction to the real folder in  `D:\SharedCodeDir`

**Question**:
In `Visual Studio 2013 / 2015`, using Microsoft Git provider, how do I properly add my solution / project to Git source control, and which git attributes in the config gile if any I have to set, so that my "shared" files in `D:\SharedCodeDir` are properly accounted for (i.e. being tracked)?

Behavior I want:

Sample Case:
1) Suppose `codefile1.txt` is first being edited from VS as part of Solution 1. Then it is committed.
2) Then that same `codefile1.txt` is edited in some other program or from VS but from Solution 2 (in which case, it too is committed to Solution 2's repo at the end).
3) Now, when I get back to Solution 1, VS / git should alert me that there were changes to `codefile1.txt` since the last commit and ask me what I want to do.

Now, if `codefile1.txt` is not committed in step 1), that is it is checked out but not checked back in, I should be able to edit it outside VS or from another solution and it should behave as a normal linked file (VS alerting me of the fact that the file has changed since it was opened, if the file is opened in VS and has been changed outside). Then, I should just commit it as part of a solution that uses the file, so that it will be committed with all the latest changes to the solution's repo.

Finally, under no circumstances, should any Git-bound solution / repo attempt to replace the physical file at `D:\SharedCodeDir\codefile1.txt` with the latest version that they have committed (in cases they are different). It should only alert me of the fact that the files are different and what I want to do (replace the `D:\SharedCodeDir\codefile1.txt`with the one from repo, or the other way around).

Also, I do not want `D:\SharedCodeDir\codefile1.txt` to be copied locally by Git to `D:\SharedCodeDir\Solution\Project\codefile1.txt` as another physical file. That is `D:\SharedCodeDir\Solution\Project\codefile1.txt` should always be a link of some sort (as described in alternatives 1 - 4 above) to the real file in `D:\SharedCodeDir\codefile1.txt` .

So how can I achieve this setup?

If it is really not possible with Git, how about SVN or alternatives?

Comment: Shared, pinned, files are a bad idea in general. And it will probably confuse the hell out of Visual Studio as well. If you really want this, put teh shared stuff in their own repository and use the "add as link" feature in Visual Studio.

Comment: Or play around with Submodules/Subtree (which Visual Studio Tools for Git doesn't support).

Comment: How would putting shared files in their own repo help? First of, I would have to manually check them out and in (instead of doing it from VS from the solution I am working with), and second they might still be added to solution's repository depending on the setup.

Comment: Because it would clearly signify that the file is shared. It would also allow it to be versioned independently. Having the same file at different versions in different repositories is an accident waiting to happen.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, very similar to yours, I did the following:

1. Added files outside my solution folder using Add As Link in Visual Studio. These file links will be placed in a certain folder inside my solution.

In my case, these files will be shared with other projects and so each project will do the next step:

2. To physically copy these files from lets say D:\SharedCode\*.cs to D:\MyProject\Shared*.cs I edited .csproj file and added the following just before the 
   `</Project>` tag

```xml
<Target Name="CopyLinkedFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
<Copy SourceFiles="%(Compile.Identity)" DestinationFiles="%(Compile.Link)" 
SkipUnchangedFiles="true" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" Condition="'%(Compile.Link)'
!= ''" />
</Target>
```

So in this case all folders will work on newest copy of the shared files but still git will treat them as they were part of the specific project.

Note: If you need to link Content files(Resources,*.txt..) instead of Compile files(*.cs), replace **Compile.** with **Content.** in the code above